# Spring REST set base URL by module

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot

I'm developing a Spring application with a modular design.
I have a main module that references submodules that can be REST endpoints :

```
server-main-module (package com.company.server.main)
|
|_user_management_apis_submodule (package com.company.server.user)
|
|_admin_rest_apis_submodule (package com.company.server.admin)
|
|_business_rest_apis_submodule (package com.company.server.api)
```

The modules are also defined as projects and have their own pom.xml
Is there a way to define a base url to each of the submodules using Spring configuration?
e.g. When I go to `/admin` I am redirected to the admin REST endpoints of the admin submodule.

EDIT : Added comment content after jan_zyka's comment:

I mean, I would like to use `@RequestMapping("book")` instead of `@RequestMapping("/admin/book")` in my admin submodule. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: I think you want to have one context but different per-moudle `@RequestMapping` ... ?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I edited my question accordingly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can:

Build each module into different war. This would make servlet container add default war name at the start of url, for all the content in war.
Change routing in dispatcher-servlet.xml for each module and prefix that with the name you want.

These 2 would work if these modules are all "subprojects".

Ultimately you can fiddle with you dispatcher-servlet to map everything the way you want.

Comment: Will those war share the same Application Context? This is the most important part in fact.

Comment: @mrik974 Yes, if you have them in same maven project, using root-pom archetype or something similar, they would have the same application context.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I'm going to try this. One last question then, where should I put the `main` method with this pattern?

Comment: @mrik974 what do you mean by `main` mehtod?

Comment: Maybe it works another way using war files, but Spring Boot, with `spring-boot-maven-plugin` needs a `main()` method to run. In my actual code this method is in a class named `Application.class` and it just contains `public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args); }`

Comment: Nevermind, I found my answer there : http://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war-maven/ .